# How to change max_length of username in AbstractUser

Tags: django, abstractuser

```
Model.py

class User(AbstractUser):
  username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Why does the phrase below appear in cmd?

WARNINGS:
ourtube.User: (auth.W004) 'User.username' is named as the 'USERNAME_FIELD', but it is not unique.
HINT: Ensure that your authentication backend(s) can handle non-unique usernames.

Comment: Your username which is named as USERNAME_FIELD is not unique. You should add unique=True to make this field unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are not mentioning the unique=True in username fields.

```
  username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

change to

```
      username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
```

Comment: oh yeah~! Thanks~!